# Shorthand for class names targeted with regex

Tags: regex, css, bem

Due to the nature of using BEM in the project I am working on, I find myself and others using the following in our CSS files:

```
[class*="something"] { ... }
[class*="__something-else"] { ... }
[class*="--other-stuff"] { ... }
[class*="more-things"] { ... }
[class*="__even-more"] { ... }
```

Is there an advisable workaround to shorten the above to prevent tedious repetition of the word `class`, or should we stick by this method?

Comment: Can you give an example context in which you needed to match bem style selectors like this in your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use preprocessor like `LESS` or `SCSS`/`Sass`.

I use `SCSS` to demonstrate your idea.

By using `@mixin` and `@content`, you can create a class selector's generator function:

```
@mixin contain($name) {
  [class*=#{$name}] {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Create a new contain selector:

```
@include contain(--big) {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/twxia/pLy3bz44/2/

This seems not shorter than only typing `[class*=...]`, but if you use `Sass` you can generate the `@mixin` like this:

```
+contain(--big)
  font-weight: bold
  font-size: 50px
```

I think use autocomplete plugin for editor or Sass will sovle your problem :D